# Why rc-status changes ip_forward state and how to prevent it?

Tags: networking, gentoo, openrc

I've got some issue with gentoo rc-status (currently using `sys-apps/openrc-0.45.2-r1` but it was happening long time before this version). From time to time some of machines are loosing ip_forwarding. I've narrowed it to running rc-status right now.

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward; rc-status; cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
 * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
Runlevel: default
[SOME SERVICES LISTED HERE]
Dynamic Runlevel: hotplugged
Dynamic Runlevel: needed/wanted
Dynamic Runlevel: manual
[SOME SERVICES LISTED HERE]
0
```

What could be possible reason behind this logic of this tricky changing of `ip_forwarding` state?

Also this happens from time to time. I need to wait a couple of days / weeks before another rc-status takes down ip_forwarding.
Key difference here is that `Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]` does not appear when ip_forwarding is not touched.